# In SwiftUI, why should I use @Bindable if @State works just fine in its place?

Tags: swiftui, observable, bindable

Please help me understand the difference between @Bindable and @State.

If I take the following example from the Xcode Documentation and change @Bindable with @State like this: `@State var book: Book`, it would work just fine.

```
@Observable
class Book: Identifiable {
    var title = "Sample Book Title"
    var isAvailable = true
}


struct BookEditView: View {
    @Bindable var book: Book
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss


    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Title", text: $book.title)


            Toggle("Book is available", isOn: $book.isAvailable)


            Button("Close") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The same would apply to more complex examples as well.

So why should I ever consider using @Bindable if @State works the same way?

Comment: State is a source of truth it is where you create the object, Bindable lets you edit an object that “lives” somewhere else. State has storage within SwiftUI Bindable does not.

Answer (score 2):

Before iOS 17, you would use `@State` for value types (`String`, `Int`, `Bool`, `struct`, `enum`). If you needed to modify that state from a child view, you would use `@Binding` and pass it as a parameter. If, instead of a value type you had a reference type (`class` conforming `ObservableObject`), then you would use `@StateObject` in the view that owned that model. In the child view that needed to modify that model, you would use `@ObservedObject`.

With iOS 17 and the Observable protocol, there is some simplification to this. `@State` is now used for both value types and reference types. Therefore, you use `@State` in the view that you want to own the model. For child views, if you want to modify the state of an `@Observable` object, you use `@Bindable`. For value types, you still use `@Binding`.

If the child view does not need to modify the models, then you don't need to add any property wrapper.

```swift
// Before

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var showTextField = false
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $showTextField) {
                Text("Show text field")
            }

            ChildView(isVisible: $showTextField, viewModel: viewModel)

            Text("Input: \(viewModel.text)")
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var isVisible: Bool
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if isVisible {
            TextField("Name", text: $viewModel.text)
        } else {
            Button {
                isVisible.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Show text field")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
// After

@Observable class ViewModel {
    var text = ""
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var showTextField = false
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $showTextField) {
                Text("Show text field")
            }

            ChildView(isVisible: $showTextField, viewModel: viewModel)

            Text("Input: \(viewModel.text)")
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var isVisible: Bool
    @Bindable var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if isVisible {
            TextField("Name", text: $viewModel.text)
        } else {
            Button {
                isVisible.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Show text field")
            }
        }
    }
}
```